# Implementation for update method in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jersey

I want to write a method for updating a book. The parameters I am passing are updated book and the id of the same book. I am confused about the exact way to implement the update method. Should I pass id in the path param or not because id is already contained in the updated book which I am passing.

BookController

```
 @PUT
@Path("/{isbn}")
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public BookResourceRto updateBook(BookResourceRto book, @PathParam("isbn") String isbn){

    Book updatedBook = bookRtoTransformer.apply(updatedBookRto);

    return bookModelTransformer.apply(bookService.updateBook(updatedBook));}
```

BookService

```
public Book updateBook(Book updatedBook) {

    BookRepoRto bookRepoRto = bookModelTransformer.apply(updatedBook);

    return bookRepoRtoTransformer.apply(bookRepository.save(bookRepoRto));
}
```

Comment: It would be best if you validated `isbn` before updating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the book is a resource, you should pass the id to the request, though it is already getting in through the book resource in request body. But you need to specify the id in the path param

Answer (score 1):

Following the RFC 7231, the answer is yes "The PUT method requests that the
state of the target resource be created or replaced with the state defined by the representation enclosed in the request message payload." You need to pass the id on the URL, because your book is a resource, so there must be a way to find it, since an URL is a resource locator.